# Quick Basic Colon Line Separator

Tags: qbasic

I am working on some old qbasic code.  It's a mess with all the Goto statements.  Am I correct that the following line will always return?

```
IF FLAG = 0 THEN TARGET = X: GOSUB 55000: TEMP = XI - TEMP2: RETURN
```

So if I understand this correctly the colon separates statements on the same line.  The `if` only pertains to TARGET = X.   The GOSUB, TEMP =, and RETURN will always execute. Correct?

Part of my confusion is because the very next line reads

```
IF FLAG = 1 THEN STEP = X: GOSUB 115000
```

And since the label to the second statement is never used in a GOTO I can't see that it would ever get executed.

Comment: Is this "Nibbles" or "Gorilla"?

Comment: @JoeEnos Neither.  It's some old IEEE code.

Comment: At least it isn't PL/I though: [`if then then then = else; else else = if;`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14057?redir=13395). Modern languages have reserved keywords for a reason... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Yes, I believe your assessment is correct. The colon is a statement separator that lets you have multiple statements on the same line. Assuming your subroutine at 55000 returns, this line should return as well.</strike>

I was wrong. Running this program:

```
if 1=2 then print "Never printed" : print "how about this?"
print "End of program"
```

on [qb64.net](http://qb64.net) prints only `End of program`. I assume that its grammar details are the same as Qbasic's, although it is a reverse-engineered effort.

As an aside, this code is written in a pre-QBasic style (e.g. using GOSUB and line numbers). There is a script that often came with QBasic (remline.bas, I believe it was called) that is supposed to help translate these kinds of programs to a newer style. I have never used it myself, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I must say the only thing worse than spaghetti code is poorly written spaghetti code.

Comment: I found this link that seems to say my assumption is wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367325/vb-net-if-statement-and-the-colon

Comment: Well, I just tested it at [qb64.net](http://qb64.net), which apparently has an online interface to their implementation now, and it turns out that I was wrong. Thanks for letting me know so I can edit my response :).

Comment: And just in case someone else comes across this, the code: if 1=2 then print "Never printed" : print "how about this?" : else print "this prints", will print "this prints". In other words, the else is still executed even after the colon.