# QuickBASIC variable only used on one line.

Tags: basic

I have been asked to convert a QuickBASIC program into c. I do not know BASIC at all. There is a line within a while loop that looks something like:

```
var_a = var_b * (1.5 * var_c - .5 * var_d) : var_d = var_c
```

var_d appears no where else in the code, what is going on here? Is var_d going to be initialized at 0 then basically stay one loop behind var_c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon operator just separates statements. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367325/if-statement-and-the-colon) This line of code is equivalent to:

```
var_a = var_b * (1.5 * var_c - .5 * var_d)
var_d = var_c
```

If var_d isn't referenced then it's just a useless statement.